# Why do we update step-size for constant step-size FISTA?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For the fast iterative shrinkage algorithm, the [authors write](https://people.rennes.inria.fr/Cedric.Herzet/Cedric.Herzet/Sparse_Seminar/Entrees/2012/11/12_A_Fast_Iterative_Shrinkage-Thresholding_Algorithmfor_Linear_Inverse_Problems_(A._Beck,_M._Teboulle)_files/Breck_2009.pdf)

[image]

Can someone explain why this algorithm is for constant step-size, when the step-size $t_k$ is obviously dynamically varying?

Comment: Alex is correct. $t_k$ is not the step size; it is a momentum factor. The step size is $1/L$. But the fact of the matter is that a fixed step size kills performance, so in practice, you _are_ going to want to adapt the value of $L$ you use.

Comment: @MichaelGrant do you know simple and effective policy for the step size? Adaptation of backtracking to Prox or are there methods beyond that?

Comment: How can this momentum factor $t_k$ be derived?  Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$t_k$ is not the step-size. It's an internal parameter of the algorithm, which does *not* depend on the functions $f$ and $g$ which make up the objective. In many cases it is called the *momentum factor*.

The step size is $\frac{1}{L}$, and it is indeed constant. You can see that in every iteration the $L$ is the same (step 4.1). See the definition of $p_L$ in the paper.

Comment: How can this momentum factor $t_k$ be derived?

Comment: Derived in Lemma 4.1 in the original paper, linked to by the author of this question. It's quite involved. There is no simple explanation for that.

Comment: @learner Look up the book by Bubeck.